Condition in a function to stop it when called in a loop?
Please consider this simple function:
def my_func(x):
    if x > 5:
        print(x)
    else:
        quit()

    print('this should be printed only if x > 5')

Then if we call this function in a loop:
for i in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:
    my_func(i)

Expected output:
6
this should be printed only if x > 5
7
this should be printed only if x > 5

But quit actually disconnects the Kernel.
I know that the following function will work but I do not want to have the second print up there:
def my_func(x):
    if x > 5: 
        print(x)
        print('this should be printed only if x > 5')
    else:
        pass

Lastly, I know that if I put the loop inside the function, I can use continue or break but I prefer to keep the function simple and instead put the function call in a loop.
So, what needs to change in the first function to achieve the expected output?

Is this what you're looking for? How to stop a function. TLDR use return to exit a function.

Indeed, quit() will quit the application.  If what you want is to return from the function, return does exactly that:
def my_func(x):
    if x > 5: print(x)
    else: return

    print('this should be printed only if x > 5')

for i in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:
    my_func(i)

This has nothing to do with loops.  return simply ends execution of the function and returns control to where the function was called.  If that control happens to be in a loop then control is now back in a loop.

The best way to approach this would be to check for the inverse condition and return early. IE
def my_func(x):
    if x < 5:
        return

    print(f'{x}\nthis should be printed only if x > 5')


This pattern is called a guard statement

To end the function prematurely you can use return.
def my_func(x):
    if x > 5: print(x)
    else: return False

    print('this should be printed only if x > 5')


Definitely, but why False?

just a habit, helps to debug
